# Basic React/Typescript how to move the code into components?

Tags: reactjs

I have issues to understand some React basics. I have made the logistics calculator. I can make it work like this, but I want to develop it further and move parts to components. I have no idea how to do that. I'd like to have that cartValue calculation in it's own component and also the button that calculates the total fee.
Could somebody give me advice where to start? Thank you folks in advance!

```
function App() {
    const [cartValue, setCartValue] = useState(0);
    const [deliveryDistance, setDeliveryDistance] = useState(0);
    const [fee, setFee] = useState(0);

    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let surcharge = 30;
        const baseFee = 5;
        let additionalFee = 5;
    
        if (cartValue < 100) {
          surcharge = 10 - cartValue;
          console.log(cartValue);
        }
    
        if (deliveryDistance > 1000) {
          additionalFee = Math.ceil((deliveryDistance - 1000) / 500);
          additionalFee = additionalFee > 0 ? additionalFee : 1;
        }
        console.log(additionalFee);
        
        setFee(baseFee + additionalFee);
  };

        return (
            <div>
              <h1>Calculate delivery fee</h1>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <label>Cart Value</label>
                <input 
                  type="number" 
                  value={cartValue} 
                  onChange={(e) => setCartValue(parseFloat(e.target.value))}/>€ 
                <br />    
                <label>Delivery distance</label> 
                <input 
                  type="number"
                  value={deliveryDistance}
                  onChange={(e) => setDeliveryDistance(parseFloat(e.target.value))}/>miles
                  <button type="submit">Calculate delivery price</button>
                </form>
                <h3>Delivery price {fee} USD/h3>

                </div>
                );
                }
```

Comment: Your best option is to use React's context api and create a provider.  This might help: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-context-for-beginners/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters I think you to learn the basic of react and how components works. The react documentation is good at explaining the basic: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html.

You can extract anything into components. A component is just a function that returns mark up like this

```
export function MyTestComponent() {

  return (
    <h1>My Test!</h1>
  );
}
```

You can then use that component anywhere in your react code.

```
export default function App() {
  
  return (<div>
    <h1>My App</h1>
    <MyTestComponent />
    </div>
    
  )
}
```

I made your example code component based and also put in the use of a custom hook which is good for abstracting away logic code like your calculator:

```
import { useState } from "react";

interface CartValueProps {
  onchange(value: number): void;
  cartValue: number;
}

export function CartValue(props: CartValueProps) {
  const { onchange, cartValue } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <label>Cart Value</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={cartValue}
        onChange={(e) => onchange(parseFloat(e.target.value))}
      />
    </>
  );
}

interface DeliveryDistanceProps {
  onchange(value: number): void;
  deliveryDistance: number;
}

export function DeliveryDistance(props: DeliveryDistanceProps) {
  const { onchange, deliveryDistance } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <label>Delivery distance</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={deliveryDistance}
        onChange={(e) => onchange(parseFloat(e.target.value))}
      />
      miles
    </>
  );
}

interface CalculateTotalProps {
  cartValue: number;
  deliveryDistance: number;
}

export function useCalculateTotal() {
  const [fee, setFee] = useState<number>(0);

  const calculateTotal = (cartValue: number, deliveryDistance: number) => {
    let surcharge = 30;
    const baseFee = 5;
    let additionalFee = 5;

    if (cartValue < 100) {
      surcharge = 10 - cartValue;
      console.log(cartValue);
    }

    if (deliveryDistance > 1000) {
      additionalFee = Math.ceil((deliveryDistance - 1000) / 500);
      additionalFee = additionalFee > 0 ? additionalFee : 1;
    }
    console.log(additionalFee);

    setFee(baseFee + additionalFee);
  };

  return { calculateTotal, fee };
}

export default function App() {
  const [cartValue, setCartValue] = useState(0);
  const [deliveryDistance, setDeliveryDistance] = useState(0);
  const { calculateTotal, fee } = useCalculateTotal();

  const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    calculateTotal(cartValue, deliveryDistance);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Calculate delivery fee</h1>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <CartValue
          cartValue={cartValue}
          onchange={(value) => setCartValue(value)}
        />
        <br />
        <DeliveryDistance
          deliveryDistance={deliveryDistance}
          onchange={(value) => setDeliveryDistance(value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Calculate delivery price</button>
      </form>
      <h3>Delivery price {fee} USD</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I made a working example here:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/morning-night-ioyl52?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A2%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A102%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D

Comment: Thanks for the great example! Now I'm trying to move the components to their own files. If I cut for example lines from interface CartValue down the end of that function, add them to their own component file, insert export default CartValue; and import the component to App.tsx it doesn't work anymore. What is the trick to get the data passed back to App.tsx?

Comment: I moved the components to its own files in the codesandbox example in my post above. Have a look there to see how it is done. Please mark my post as correct answer if you find it helpful.